# xcode 9.0.1 can be run on macOS Sierra 10.12.4?

Tags: ios, macos-sierra, xcode9

macOS Sierra 10.12.4 is compatible For xcode 9.0.1 or Compulsory we need to update macOS Sierra 10.12.6 ?

can you guys know this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [its page in the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12), Xcode requires macOS Sierra 10.12.6 or higher, so you must update macOS if you're on 10.12.4

Comment: This answer is not helpful unless you specify WHICH VERSION of Xcode requires 10.12.6.  And the link is not helpful because that link always goes to the latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You actually **can** change the minimum required version in the Xcode bundle's plist. To do that simply control-click Xcode app, click `Open Package Contents`, then go inside `Contents` folder, there you'll see `info.plist`. Open it with Xcode you have already installed, and there you can edit value of `Minimum system version` field to whatever version you have currently installed.

[image: Minimum system version]

Comment: On an older version of macOS (10.11.6, `El Capitan`), this trick does NOT work with XCode 9.2

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that with Xcode, individual apps or plugins that's fine, but Xcode has a lot of macOS level dependencies. The Mac Apps Store will download an older version Xcode for whatever OS X/macOS version you are running.